# Multiple conditions in NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, nspredicate

How to use multiple conditions with `NSPredicate`?

I am using this but not getting anything in the returned array .

```
NSPredicate *placePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"place CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND category CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND ((dates >= %@) AND (dates <= %@)) AND ((amount >= %f) AND (amount <= %f))",placeTextField.text,selectedCategory,selectedFromDate,selectedToDate,[amountFromTextField.text floatValue],[amountToTextField.text floatValue]];

NSArray *placePredicateArray = [dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:placePredicate];

NSLog(@"placePredicateArray %@", placePredicateArray);
```

The amount and the category can be empty sometimes. How should I construct the `NSPredicate`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would tend to handle this one piecemeal.  That is,

```
placePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"place CONTAINS[cd] %@",placeTextField.text];
NSMutableArray *compoundPredicateArray = [ NSMutableArray arrayWithObject: placePredicate ]; 

if( selectedCategory != nil ) // or however you need to test for an empty category
    {
    categoryPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category CONTAINS[cd] %@",selectedCategory];
    [ compoundPredicateArray addObject: categoryPredicate ];
    }

// and similarly for the other elements.
```

Note that I don't bother even putting into the array the predicate for category (or anything else) when I know there isn't one.

```
// Then
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                                  compoundPredicateArray ];
```

And if I were planning to do it a lot, I wouldn't use the format method, but keep around the building blocks and just change whatever changes between uses.

Comment: +1 for this comment `// or however you need to test for an empty category` really helped me.. thanks! :)

Answer (score 30):

You can build your `placesPredicate` using other `NSPredicate` objects and the `NSCompoundPredicate` class

Something like :

```
NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"place CONTAINS[cd] %@", placeTextField.text];
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category CONTAINS[cd] %@", selectedCategory];
NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dates >= %@) AND (dates <= %@)", selectedFromDate,selectedToDate];
NSPredicate *p4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(amount >= %f) AND (amount <= %f)", [amountFromTextField.text floatValue],[amountToTextField.text floatValue]]; 

NSPredicate *placesPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2, p3, p4]];
```

Now, if you are missing category for example you can just use a dummy `YES` predicate to replace it :

```
NSPredicate *p2;
if (selectedCategory) {
    p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category CONTAINS[cd] %@", selectedCategory];
} else {
    p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBool:YES]
}
```

Comment: But how to get an array from NSPredicate ?

Comment: If you need to get the array of predicates used to create the compound use the `subpredicates` property of `NSCompoundPredicate`. you should also take a good look at @DRVic's answer - he creates the array of predicates dynamically as he goes along - this is a bit more efficient because he doesn't need to include any `YES` predicates but it means that you don't know which predicate is at which index in the array of subpredicates easily.

Comment: PS Only instances of `NSCompoundPredicate` will have a subpredicates array property, obviously. It doesn't make sense for a normal `NSPredicate` to be turned into an array!

Answer (score 0):

```
Suppose a class Person with attributes "name", "age", "income"

"personArray" is array of class Person

NSPredicate *mypredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(personObj Person, NSDictionary *bindings) {
     NSNumber *age = personObj.age;
     String *name = personObj.name;
     NSNumber *income = personObj.income
     BOOL result = (age > 20 && name == "Stack" && income >40000);
     return result;
}];

NSArray *filteredArray = [personArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: mypredicate];
```

For further you can read this article [Array Filter Using Blocks](http://albertmata.com/blog/2014/03/25/objective-c-array-filter-using-blocks/)

> In Swift

```
let filterArray = personArray.filter
            { person in
           let age = personObj.age;
           let name = personObj.name;
           let income = personObj.income
           BOOL result = (age > 20 && name == "Stack" && income >40000);
          return result;
        }
```